# reload groupingStore with ajax response json - Ext.getCmp('theID').getStore().reload() - not working

Tags: json, extjs, grouping, reload

Hello
So i have an ext.GridPanel with a GroupingStore. This panel is meant to display search results. When the page loads it is empty - correct. The panel should reload when the user enters search criteria and returns with valid json. I tested everything and it all works until the reload bit - which doesnt do anything. Any ideas out there? I've been sitting with this for a while.

Thanks all!

```
//global var defined....
Ext.grid.dummyData = [];
//this within Ext.onReady(function() {
var sstore = new Ext.data.GroupingStore({
    reader: sreader,
    autoLoad: false,
    data: Ext.grid.dummyData,
    sortInfo: { field: 'company', direction: "ASC" },
    groupField: 'scheme'
});

var sgrid = new sg.GridPanel({
    id:'srchGrid',
    store: sstore,
    ...

function searchNowBtn(id, txt, win) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'action.aspx',
        params: "...",
        success: function(r) {
            Ext.grid.dummyData = [['dummy1', '', '', '', ''],['dummy2', '', '', '', '']];
            Ext.getCmp('srchGrid').getStore().reload();
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

ok managed to sort it out. See the solution below for anyone else facing similar situation:

replace

```
 Ext.getCmp('srchGrid').getStore().reload();
```

with

```
 Ext.getCmp('srchGrid').getStore().loadData(Ext.grid.dummyData);
```

easy peezy :)

njoy!

Answer (score 0):

Easier way

sstore.reload();